# Something to uniquely identify a user on a computer using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a site and there is no registrations. I can use IPs to identify people but that's not always safe or accurate. Is there a way I can make it so I can identify uniquely who can edit/delete the post they posted?

Also.. a note. People can post messages but can only edit or delete within the first 5 minutes so it's not like I'm checking forever. I'm only checking for 5 minutes and then they can't do anything. Also the IP, I guess, is bad for people who do it in like a workplace or school.

Comment: I don't know the situation or if this may be of use, but consider this: http://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: panopticlick isn't intended to be an example of best practice, it's a warning.  Just set a cookie on any user that submits content, and tie that cookie to all content they create.  Only allow them to edit/delete if they have the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's only for a few minutes a cookie with a unique session id in it would probably do the trick.  There could be edge cases where a user has cookies disabled, but it should be fine the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Thanks, I was going with cookie but wanted to see if there was any other viable options. Heh. guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's no registrations, you can still drop a cookie.

Generate a UUID, put it in a cookie, and use that.

Comment: PHP's built-in session handling should be sufficient, really.  No need to reinvent the wheel.